# Hadoop's passage of parameter

Tags: hadoop, parameters, mapper

I've known that a writable object can be passed to mapper using something like:

DefaultStringifier.store(conf, object ,"key");

object = DefaultStringifier.load(conf, "key", Class );

My question is:

In a mapper I read out the object then change the value of this object,

for example: object=another .

How to do to make sure that the change of the object's value

could be known by the next time of mapper task?

Is there any better way to pass parameter to mapper?

Answer (score 0):

Use the file system instead. Write the value in HDFS, and replace the file with a different content. Neither config nor DistributedCache are not appropiate for mutable state.